# LINQ statement no longer works after being wrapped into an extension method

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, extension-methods

I had a need for a method that could take a collection of strings, and replace all occurrences of a specific string with another.

For example, if I have a `List<string>` that looks like this:

```
List<string> strings = new List<string> { "a", "b", "delete", "c", "d", "delete" };
```

and I want to replace "delete" with "", I would use this LINQ statement:

```
strings = (from s in strings select (s=="delete" ? s=String.Empty : s)).ToList();
```

and it works great.  But then I figured I should make it an extension method, since I'd likely use it again later.  In this case, I just want to write the following:

```
strings.ReplaceStringInListWithAnother( "delete", String.Empty);
```

While my code compiles, and the LINQ statement works inside of the extension method, when I return the collection reverts back to its original contents:

```
public static void ReplaceStringInListWithAnother( this List<string> my_list, string to_replace, string replace_with)
{
    my_list = (from s in my_list select (s==to_replace ? s=replace_with : s)).ToList();
}
```

So it would seem that I just modified a copy of the List...  but when I looked at the code for Pop, it modifies the collection similarly, yet the changes stick, so my assumption was that my method's parameter declarations are correct.

Can anyone explain what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: As a general comment, there is no need to use `string.Empty` anymore. It is a remnant of C# 1.0. Your code is going to be more readable if you just use `""`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The LINQ statement you wrote does not modify the collection, it actually creates a new one.

The extension method you wrote creates this new collection and then discards it. The assignment is redundant: you’re assigning to a local parameter, which goes out of scope immediately after.

When you’re calling the method, you’re also discarding its result instead of assigning it back.

Therefore, you should write the method like this:

```
public static List<string> ReplaceStringInListWithAnother(
    this List<string> my_list, string to_replace, string replace_with)
{
    return (from s in my_list select
        (s == to_replace ? replace_with : s)).ToList();
}
```

and the call like this:

```
strings = strings.ReplaceStringInListWithAnother("delete", "");
```

---

By the way, you can make the function more useful by making it generic:

```
public static List<T> ReplaceInList<T>(this List<T> my_list,
    T to_replace, T replace_with) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return (from s in my_list select
        (s.Equals(to_replace) ? replace_with : s)).ToList();
}
```

This way you can use it for other things, not just `string`s. Furthermore, you can also declare it to use `IEnumerable<T>` instead of `List<T>`:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ReplaceItems<T>(this IEnumerable<T> my_list,
    T to_replace, T replace_with) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    return from s in my_list select (s.Equals(to_replace) ? replace_with : s);
}
```

This way you can use it for any collection of equatable items, not just `List<T>`. Notice that `List<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so you can still pass a List into this function. If you want a list out, simply call `.ToList()` after the call to this one.

**Update:** If you actually want to replace elements *in a list* instead of creating a new one, you can still do that with an extension method, and it can still be generic, but you can’t use Linq and you can’t use `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
public static void ReplaceInList<T>(this List<T> my_list,
    T to_replace, T replace_with) where T : IEquatable<T>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < my_list.Count; i++)
        if (my_list[i].Equals(to_replace))
            my_list[i] = replace_with;
}
```

This will not return the new list, but instead modify the old one, so it has a *void* return type like your original.

Comment: As a comment, however, I would recommend to remove the `.ToList()` inside the method; return `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `List<string>`; and to call `.ToList()` after the call to `ReplaceStringInListWithAnother`. That way can use the same method in situations where you don’t want a `List<string>`.

Comment: @Timwi: And, to extend your advice further, I'd say the OP might as well just accept any `IEnumerable<string>` at that point rather than strictly a `List<string>`.

Comment: I'd also probably not name it `ReplaceStringInListWithAnother` if it now operates on any `IEquatable<T>` and not just strings but +1 otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and help, guys.  I was wondering if I had to use a return statement instead, but couldn't find that in the MSDN tutorial.  Fantastic!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint: what do you expect the below code to do?

```
void SetToTen(int y)
{
    y = 10;
}

int x = 0;
SetToTen(x);
```

Hopefully, you understand that the `SetToTen` method above does nothing meaningful, since it only changes the value of its own local variable `y` and has no effect on the variable whose value was passed to it (in order for that to happen, the `y` parameter would have to be of type `ref int` and the method would be called as `SetToTen(ref x)`).

Keeping in mind that extension methods are really just static methods in fancy clothes, it should be clear why your `ReplaceStringInListWithAnother` is not doing what you expected: it is only setting its **local** `my_list` variable to a new value, having no effect on the original `List<string>` passed to the method.

Now, it's worth mentioning that the only reason this is not working for you is that your code works by **setting a variable to a new object***. If you were to *modify* the `List<string>` passed to `ReplaceStringInListWithAnother`, everything would work just fine:

```
public static void ReplaceStringInListWithAnother( this List<string> my_list, string to_replace, string replace_with)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < my_list.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (my_list[i] == to_replace)
        {
            my_list[i] = replace_with;
        }
    }
}
```

It's *also* worth mentioning that `List<string>` is an overly restrictive parameter type for this method; you could achieve the same functionality for any type implementing `IList<string>` (and so I'd change the `my_list` parameter to be of type `IList<string>`).

---

*Reading your question again, it seems clear to me that this is the main point of confusion for you. The important thing you have to realize is that by default, everything in C# is passed by value. With value types (anything defined as a `struct` -- `int`, `double`, `DateTime`, and many more), the *thing that's passed* is the value itself. With reference types (anything that's defined as a `class`), the *thing that's passed* is a **reference to an object**. In the latter case, all method calls on references to objects of mutable types do actually affect the underlying object, since multiple variables of reference type can point to the same object. But *assignment* is different from a method call; if you assign a reference to an object that has been passed by value to some new reference to an object, you are doing nothing to the underlying object, and therefore nothing is happening that would be reflected by the original reference.

This is a really important concept that many .NET developers struggle with. But it's also a topic that's been explained thoroughly elsewhere. If you need more explanation, let me know and I'll try to dig up a link to a page that makes all of this as clear as possible.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but in your example, isn't it a bit difference since you're using a value type in your params list, instead of a reference type?  I had assumed that in my case, when using a List<>, that I was going to be given a reference, and that it was okay to reassign it.  Oops!

Comment: @Dave: Did my update clarify things for you, or just muddle them further? It seems you were on the right track; but as I hope you now see, you were holding an inaccurate view of what it means to pass a reference type as a parameter to a method.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't *shown* the code for "Pop" so it's hard to know what you mean. You talk about "when I return the collection" but you're *not* returning anything - the method has a `void` return type.

LINQ typically doesn't change the contents of an existing collection. Usually you should return a *new* collection from the extension method. For example:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReplaceAll
    (this IEnumerable<string> myList, string toReplace, string replaceWith)
{
    return toReplace.Select(x => x == toReplace ? replaceWith : x);
}
```

(I've made it more general here - you shouldn't start materializing lists unless you really need to.)

You'd then call it with:

```
strings = strings.ReplaceAll("delete", "").ToList();
```

... or change the type of `string` to `IEnumerable<string>` and just use

```
strings = strings.ReplaceAll("delete", "");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, Jon.  I have a bad habit of just using List<> everywhere, since I haven't yet been bitten in the butt by forcing a specific collection type.  Time to change my ways!

I like your code example... thank you.